# $R$ is a relation then $dom R, range R$ are sets, $\cup \cup R^{-1}= \cup \cup R$ and $dom R \cup range R = \cup \cup R $

Tags: set-theory

**Definition** $\mathbf{1.}$ Let a class $A$ we define $\cup A \{ x : \exists a \in A \mbox{ such that } (x \in a)\}$

$\mathbf{2.}$ $A^{-1}=\{(x,y): (y,x) \in A\}$, $dom A=\{x : \exists y \mbox{ such that } (x,y) \in A\}$, $rangeA=\{y : \exists x \mbox{ such that } (x,y) \in A\}$

$\mathbf{3.}$ We say $R$ is a relation such that $\forall x\in R$, exists $y,z$ such that $x=(y,z)$

**Problems** $1.$ If $R$ is a relation and a set. Prove $dom R, range R$ are sets.

$2.$ If $R$ is a relation then $\cup \cup R^{-1}= \cup \cup R$ and $dom R \cup range R = \cup \cup R $

Solve to problem 1, we know that $domR, range R \subset \cup \cup R$ and by hypothesis $R$ is a set then $\cup \cup R$ is a set by Union Axiom then $dom R \mbox{ and } range R$ are sets.

To solve the second we have $domR \cup range R \subset \cup \cup R$, because $domR, range R \subset \cup \cup R$.

Could you help to prove $\cup \cup A \subset domR \cup range R$?, My idea is use $R \subset domR \times range R$

Comment: Hint: Problem 1 follows from Problem 2. Can you find out why?

Comment: I think I saw it, so any hint to prove $\cup \cup R = dom R \cup range R$ ?

Comment: @Aaron: First work out what $\bigcup R$ is: $x\in\bigcup R$ iff there is some $y\in R$ such that $x\in y$. The elements of $R$ are ordered pairs, so $x\in\bigcup R$ iff there is some $\langle a,b\rangle\in R$ such that $x\in\langle a,b\rangle$.

Comment: So $x \in \cup \cup R$ iff exists $y \in \cup R$ such that $x \in y$ iff there is some $(a,b) \in R $ such that $ y \in (a,b)$ such that $x \in y $ how can I relate with the $domR \cup range R$?